# File Isn't Uploading Via PHP

Tags: php

I have a script that worked last year when it submitted to itself. I had to rework it so that the submitting was on its own page, but not the files aren't uploading at all! The script isn't generating any errors, so I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Here is the relevant part of the script (removed extra code):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title'])) {

    // Set POST as variables
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $time = time();
    $resumefilename = "";

    $rfilename = strtolower($_FILES['resume']['name']);
    $rfiletype = strtolower($_FILES['resume']['type']);
    $ruploadname = str_replace(" ", "-", trim($name)) . "-" . str_replace( " ", "-", trim($title)) . "-resume";
    $ruploadname = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -]/s', '', $ruploadname);
    $ruploadname = strtolower($ruploadname); 

    // Folder where images will be stored
    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // SECURITY - Checks if file contains PHP and kills if positive
        $rpos = strpos($rfilename, 'php');
        if(!($rpos === false)) { die('Error, Bad File Type'); }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Resume File Check
        $file_ext = strrchr($rfilename, '.');
        $allowedExts = array(
            "pdf", 
            "doc", 
            "docx"
        ); 
        $allowedMimeTypes = array( 
            'text/pdf',
            'application/pdf',
            'application/msword',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
        );
        if (!(in_array($file_ext, $allowedExts))) {
            $error .= '<p>Invalid file type detected for Resume: please upload pdf, doc, or docx files only. Thank you.</p>';
        }

        if(in_array($_FILES["resume"]["type"], $allowedMimeTypes)){  
            $ruploadfile = $uploaddir.$time.'-'.$ruploadname.$file_ext;
            $resumefilename = $time.'-'.$ruploadname.$file_ext;
            $remailname = $ruploadname.$file_ext;

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'], $ruploadfile)) {
                $resumesuccess = 1;
            } else {
                $resumesuccess = 0;
            }
        }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

?>

Comment: And just to cover a base question, the director does exist with the correct permissions.

Comment: Could you also show form?

Comment: Can you show me the form

Comment: I DIDN'T EVEN THINK IT COULD BE THE FORM. Of course. Sush, when I redid the form, I forgot the enctype. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="your file">`

All other code

`</form>`

Answer (score 0):

You might try this

```
if (isset($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title'])) {
// Do something
} else {
   echo '<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">';
   <!-- Field sets -->
   echo '</form>';
}
```